# What are the causes for javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

What are the causes for

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:971)
```

Even after having

- `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in applicationContext
- methods annotated with @Transactional

In Spring 3.1.1 + Hibernate 4.1

Comment: The post below might help




 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544157/no-transaction-in-progress-exception-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must surround calling code with a transaction. In Spring you can use `@Transactional` annotation or AOP transaction demarcation. It's a very broad topic, start from [*11. Transaction Management*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) in official documentation.

For starters define JPA transaction manager bean (chances are you already have one), add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` and annotate your method with `@Transactional`.

Comment: I would like to know what are the circumstances where @Transactional does not work